# Reasons for "bin dir change or directory rename" app restart? (Fixed i think)

Tags: asp.net, bin, connection-timeout, application-restart

### Update / FIX

Well I did two things which seemed to have it work

1. Changed my app pool's Advanced settings >> Process Model>> identity to "Network Service"
2. Directed it to use a temp folder for compilation on the sites .net compilation settings. There is still a restart every once in a while but the session doesn't get lost, and all browsers can still connect.

This also worked: http://www.aaronblake.co.uk/blog/2009/09/28/bug-fix-application-restarts-on-directory-delete-in-asp-net/

I am building my web app in asp.net 4 and am having much trouble figuring out why my connection is timing out after about a minute (when browsed to - hosted using IIS 7). I have been informed that this is probably due to the web.config/directory being edited, and therefore the app being unloaded/restarted and the page dies. I am not aware of any code I wrote explicitly editing anything on the bin.

I am connecting to sql (through table adapters or SQLConnection Class) but I don't think that would do anything.  Also I am using buttons which run as scripts.

I have set the restart on config change option to false in IIS with no avail still..

### EDIT

Here are some event logs of the shutdown.

```
_shutDownMessage=Change Notification for critical directories.
bin dir change or directory rename
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
HostingEnvironment caused shutdown
Change Notification for critical directories.
bin dir change or directory rename
Change Notification for critical directories.
bin dir change or directory rename
Change Notification for critical directories.
bin dir change or directory rename

_shutDownStack=   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownWithoutDemand()
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ShutdownAppDomain(String stackTrace)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.OnCriticalDirectoryChange(Object sender, FileChangeEvent e)
   at System.Web.FileChangesMonitor.OnCriticaldirChange(Object sender, FileChangeEvent e)
   at System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.FireNotifications()
   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.CallCallbackWithAssert(WorkItemCallback callback)
   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.OnQueueUserWorkItemCompletion(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Have been straining my brain thinking of why bin would be getting changed. at a complete loss, nothing we wrote writes anything/changes anything in there knowingly

Comment: Just a clarification- you have a single browser running a single request connected for a minute (presumably processing some slow page logic) and then it gets an HTTP disconnect or some other error?

Comment: What exception are you getting? SQL timeout?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you mean by "my connection is timing out after about a minute". Is this a file download? A page load? A long-running SQL query? Or do you perhaps mean session timeout or authentication timeout? I can't think of any reason your web.config would be modified during execution of your code. Are you writing anything to your application's \bin directory? That might cause an app restart.

Comment: What is timing out? Sessions are timing out? Database connections? Or is the application just restarting every minute?

Comment: The application pool can auto restart for many reasons. Editing a config value, file manipulation not in App_Data, memory limits getting hit, too many recompilation, and several others. I suggest debugging or profiling the page to see where in the process it is taking so long. You may want to post applicable configuration data (without IPs and passwords of course).

Comment: hey thanks for all the answers.  I get no exception thrown (or at least displayed) what so ever.  If i continue to perform actions without letting the site idle for around a minute or so there are no problems.  The database queries perform as expected.  After leaving idle for minute or so, then clicking a button/link/ect gives rise to a page that says nothing but "Your connection has timed out".  Everything does of course work in the debugger, just not when live.  @chris - yes thats exactly right.  -- its a client side time out message in the browser. thanks.

Comment: What browser are you using for testing?  Chrome has serious timeout issues if you have the default windows configuration for proxy settings.

Comment: @Chris - I am using firefox 6 for the most part, but switch to IE 9 sometimes, my partner has been using IE 9 and firefox 5.  Tested it in Chrome, but same problems

Comment: What is your global.asax file doing?

Comment: @I had no global.asax file until last night when i added one to trace the shutdown.  After logging I removed the global.asax.  Occurs either way.  --Edit: my global.asax is just this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/14/433194.aspx , but emailing me the log instead of using NT Event Log.

Comment: after watching shut down logs for a while, it seems to be shutting down from "bin dir change or directory rename" constantly (10+ times an hour).  Sometimes there is a "Change notification for critical directories" following in the log, others not -- even without anyone browsing to the site.